# What does it means that electric charge is conserved but not quantized?

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, charge, discrete, magnetic-monopoles

I always thought electric charge is quantized until someone told me in writing that there is no such thing as magnetic monopole which suggests electric charge isn't quantized. Then what the difference between conserved quantity and quantized?

Comment: Dirac noted that the existence of a magnetic monopole would imply that electric charge must be quantised, but the non-existence of magnetic monopoles does not mean charge is not quantised.

Comment: Electric charge is quantized and magnetic monopoles strictly do not exist, so I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no relationship between conserved quantities and quantised quantities. Any conserved quantity will obey the continuity equation, which basically says that the change in the charge in a certain volume over some time is equal to the charge generated in the volume minus the charge that exited through the surface enclosing the volume.

While quantisation of some quantity means that the quantity comes in small packets or units. There is no relation between a quantity being quantised and a quantity being conserved.

Example:

In fluid flow one can write the continuity equation for fluids mass, because mass is conserved. But it is not quantised.